# Stange bux with quotes

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently went into vs code and tried typing quotes. Usually, when you click on the button of quotes, they immediately appear and you can write something in them. But now, for some reason, you need to press the quotes key twice and then you need to additionally press the quotes inside to write something inside. My only extensions are Dart, flutter and color brackets.

Comment: Do you have a language selected (usually indicated in the bottom right-hand corner)?

Comment: yes, i have. It says Dart.